# android : cancelling progressbar caught exception : android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am trying to implement a progressbar in my application.
This progressbar is visible on button click, and then a thread is also starting along with it. when the thread completes, I am trying to make invisible the progressBar. But it caught exception on excuting :

progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

exception :

**android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

my code is :

```
  Thread thredUpdate   = new Thread()
  {
     public void run()
     {
        ClearDatabase();
                 progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                      
     }
  };
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
  setProgressBarVisibility(true);
  ProgressBar progressbar  = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
  progressbar .setVisibility(View.GONE);
  btnUpdateDB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View argBtnUpdateDB)
      {                 
            setProgressBarVisibility(true);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             try
            {
                     if((progressbar.isEnabled()))
                    thredUpdate.start();
             }               
            catch(Exception exSoap) 
            {                                                                                 
                   exSoap.printStackTrace();
            }

  } });
```

How can I cancel this progressbar without calling setVisibility(View.GONE)?

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call it from UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Another approach is to use `AsyncTask` instead of regular `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to call it with a runnable

```
static Handler handler = new Handler();
...

handler.post(hideprogress);


...

static Runnable hideprogress = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Handler` to hide the progress bar:

```
private static final int HANDLER_MESSAGE_UPDATE_COMPLETE = 0;

Thread thredUpdate   = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        ClearDatabase();
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = HANDLER_MESSAGE_UPDATE_COMPLETE;
            myHandler.sendMessage(msg);                                          
    }
};

Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
        case HANDLER_MESSAGE_UPDATE_COMPLETE:
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        default:
            Log.w("MY_TAG","message type not supported: " + msg.what);
        }
    }
};
```

This approach gives you the flexibility of being able to easily add new message types to handle future changes.  It also keeps all your UI updates in one place for easier maintenance.