# Progress bar loading is not stopped when the activity is called second time

Tags: android

I have created a welcome page(launcher) and included a progress bar.next activity will be displayed after this progress bar loading(for few seconds).For the first time,when the app is run,after few seconds the next activity is displayed.Now,when i press back button,welcome activity is being displayed.But this time,after few seconds,it is now calling the next activity(using Intent) like the first time.How to resolve this?
The code is:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar p;
    private boolean mbActive;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        p = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mbActive = true;
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(mbActive && (waited < 1000)) {
                        sleep(200);
                        if(mbActive) {
                            waited += 200;
                            updateProgress(waited);
                        }
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                } finally {
                    onContinue();
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public void updateProgress(final int timePassed) {
        if(null != p) {
            final int progress = p.getMax() * timePassed / 100;
            p.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    public void onContinue() {
        Intent intd=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intd);
    }


}
```

Comment: see @Akhil Reddy you call onContinue method in onCreate method.....
so when you click back button activity on resume is called .....activity is calling its create again so if you want to call second activity again put on create ...thread code in onResume

Comment: could u plz provide me onResume sample code.I am a beginner.Thanks in advance.

Comment: i cant post code in comment because char length check didn't allow me so i added an answer to it.....

Comment: how to add onCreate thread in onResume()?

Comment: i post an answer go though it ...if have any dought plz ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :---
i change the code on keep the progress show code in on resume

```
 public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar p;
    private boolean mbActive;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    }

    public void updateProgress(final int timePassed) {
      if (null != p) {
        final int progress = p.getMax() * timePassed / 100;
        p.setProgress(progress);
      }
    }

    public void onContinue() {
      Intent intd = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intd);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      showProgress();
    }

    private void showProgress() {
      p = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
      final Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          mbActive = true;
          try {
            int waited = 0;
            while (mbActive && (waited < 1000)) {
              sleep(200);
              if (mbActive) {
                waited += 200;
                updateProgress(waited);
              }
            }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          } finally {
            onContinue();
          }
        }
      };
      timerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`setVisibility(View.GONE);/setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`** .

```
public void onContinue() 
    {
    p.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Intent intd=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intd);
    }
```

**FYI**

> CalledFromWrongThreadException is a common error if you tried to send
>   UI events to the UI thread from outside the UI thread.

For your crash case . Read **[runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))**

Comment: if i am addinh this p.setVisibility(View.GONE), the app is getting crashed.

Comment: @AkhilReddy add `onContinue();` method in `try` block

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
                                                                  Process: com.akhil.aesqrgen, PID: 5849
                                                                  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @AkhilReddy Yeah . Its a general . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978052/only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-views-on-a and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14114546/3395198

Comment: could u plz provide me sample code.I am a beginner.Thanks in advance

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499389/android-cancelling-progressbar-caught-exception-android-view-viewrootcalled

Comment: @AkhilReddy as @IntelliJ Amiya you should run the `p.setVisibility(View.Gone)` as for the crash this happens because you are modifying the ***UI*** in a Thread thats not the UI thread in this case your `timerThread`, so what you need to do is to to request the UI thread and then manipulate the UI. You can find the answer in the link that was posted in the last comment. PS: You can only manipulate UI elements in the UI thread.

Comment: yeah,understood now,Thanq

Comment: @M090009 Indeed .#Reddy Move ahead

Answer (score 0):

dismiss the Progress dialog

```
public void onContinue() 
{
p.dismiss();
Intent intd=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intd);
}
```

Comment: Where is `Progress dialog` ??